# Is Cloud Functions just a façade on top of Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I notice when I created a CF that it has hooks into Cloud Build and Cloud Run; my suspicion is that I could completely duplicate CF with the appropriate build (dockerfile, cloudbuild) and a standard NodeJS express app. Is this the case? If not, what is CF doing under the hood that makes it special? Or is it just a super-easy method to create servers in cloud for those that aren't comfortable setting up their own?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're pretty much right.  Cloud Functions is a level higher on the abstraction ladder, so it provides some conveniences automatically at the cost of flexibility/customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of Cloud Functions, [Gen 1 and Gen 2](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison):

- Gen 1 Cloud Functions are not built on top of Cloud Run. It is its own managed service.
- Gen 2 Cloud Functions are built on top of Cloud Run. It is a managed service that uses Cloud Run for its infrastructure.

As described above, Cloud Functions are meant to be a *managed* service. Yes, it's absolutely possible for you to build your own Dockerized service and run it on Cloud Run directly but you would miss out on some of the benefits of the service, for example:

- Cloud Functions can be triggered by more than just HTTP. There are multiple types of [triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling) that hook into other GCP services and Cloud Functions provide a standardized format for receiving these triggers. (Cloud Run has [preview support](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/trigger-with-events) for some triggers as well, with less flexibility and more code required)
- Cloud Functions don't require a Dockerfile and don't require you to manage the operating system. All you need is a packaged application for a targeted language version (e.g., an express app with package.json targeting Node 18) and the Functions Framework will take care of the rest.

The short version is that the Functions Framework abstracts away a lot of the work of running a Dockerized service and instead allows you to focus on the code which ultimately can result in a lower total cost of ownership.